# Downloading from S3 in node and opening in a new window

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-s3

My Angular 1 application saves files to S3 and allows for a wide variety of files types.

When I retrieve the objects I use the following code:

```
export function show(req, res) { 
    const s3 = new aws.S3();
      const s3Params = {
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
        Key: req.query.key + ''
      };
      res.attachment(req.query.key + '');
      var fileStream = s3.getObject(s3Params).createReadStream();
      fileStream.pipe(res);
}
```

I would like to open the received file on the client in a new window (just like on the AWS console) but I can't figure out how to go about it.

For example on the client side does not work at all:

```
 .then(
    (data) => {
      var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
      var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      window.open(fileURL);
    }
  )
```

I really don't understand how the concept of data streams works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was get a signedUrl for the resource for this to work much simpler than what I was trying to do.

```
export function show(req, res) {
  const s3 = new aws.S3();
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
    Key: req.query.key + ''
  };
  s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', s3Params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.end();
    }
    const returnData = {
        signedRequest: data,
    };
    res.write(JSON.stringify(returnData));
    res.end();
  });
}
```

and on the client all I have to do is open the link in a new tab:

```
openDoc(doc) {
this.$http()
  .then(
    (data) => {
      this.$window.open(data.data.signedRequest, '_blank')
    }
  )
  .catch(
    (err) => {
      this.Notification.error('failed to download attachment');
    }
  )
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to download pdf, you may open it directly from s3.

```
s3client.getResourceUrl("your-bucket", "some-path/some-key.jpg");
```

This will return you url to the file.
So you need code like:

```js
export function show(req, res) {
  this.s3client = new aws.S3({
    accessKeyId: options.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: options.secretAccessKey,
    region: options.region
  })
  let resourceUrl = s3client.getResourceUrl(S3_BUCKET, req.query.key + '');
  window.open(resourceUrl, '_blank');
}
```

I'm sorry, can't test it right now, but try. Should work.

Comment: getResourseUrl does not appear to be in the node aws library.

Comment: I've checked - you're right, there is no such method.

Comment: http(s)://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<object>
http(s)://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/<object>

Comment: But you may use patterns to build urls
http(s)://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<object>
http(s)://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/<object>

Comment: Take a look at my answer.